# Height of binary tree with L leaf nodes

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

What is the height of binary tree with L leaf nodes?

I know that in full binary tree the height is between:

```
log L  and  L-1
```

But what if the tree is not full?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.  Is this a balanced binary tree?  When you say "full," do you mean that the nth rank (where zero is the root) has 2^n leaves?

Comment: every node other than the leaves has two children

Comment: So run a thought experiment.  Take a leaf off the bottom of the tree.  What is its height?  Take leaves off until it is "full" again.  What is its height?

Comment: ho OK I am confused the height can be infinite

Comment: What? No.  What is the height of a balanced binary tree with 15 nodes?  14 nodes? 8 nodes?  7 nodes?  Draw it out on a piece of paper.  It looks like [this](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Graphics/FullBinary.jpg).

Comment: I meen if the tree is not full. so it can be infinite cause I can add infinite edges to the leaf and this will stay One leaf but infinite height

Comment: Not if it's balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked What is the height of binary tree with L leaf nodes?
but I confused. If the tree is not balanced, their is not limit...

[image]